# Solve stochastic differential equation $ dx = 3a(x^{1/3}-x)dt + 3\sqrt{a}x^{2/3}dW $

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following nonlinear stochastic differential equation

$$
dx = 3a(x^{1/3}-x)dt + 3\sqrt{a}x^{2/3}dW 
$$

According to my TA, I'm supposed to transform variables to $y=x^{1/3}$, which I do by Ito's formula:

$$
dy = \frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3} dx - \frac{2}{9}x^{-5/3}dx^2
$$

Inserting the expression for $y$ and $dx$ I get (disregarding factors larger than $dt$):

$$
dy   = -a(y^{-1} + y)dt + \sqrt{a}dW 
$$

I'm supposed to solve for $y$ and then transform back to get the solution for $x$. But, solving the equation for $y$ above doesn't seem straightforward to me at all.

Do you have any input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable transformation is right. But, there is an error in your computation of $dy$ using the Ito's formula. It should read

$$
dy = \frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3} dx - \frac{1}{9}x^{-5/3}dx^2
$$

As a result, you should obtain the following standard OU process

$$
dy   = -aydt + \sqrt{a}dW 
$$

---

To solve it, rewrite

$$d(e^{at}y)=e^{at}\sqrt{a}dW$$

with its solution given by

$$y_t=y_0e^{-at} + \sqrt{a}\int_0^te^{-a(t-s)}dW_s$$

The solution for $x$ is then

$$x_t = \left( x_0^{1/3}e^{-at} + \sqrt{a}\int_0^te^{-a(t-s)}dW_s \right)^3 $$

Comment: Thanks. So the solution for $y(t)$ is $y_0e^{-at} + g\int_0^t e^{a(s-t)dW(s)}$. Is it correct that the solution for $x$ is then $x_0^3 + g\int_0^t e^{3a(s-t)dW(s)}$, i.e., take the power of 3 of each term?

Comment: Not quite. Please see the added solution in the answer.